# Storing a floating point number as an INT?

Tags: mysql

what would be the best data type to store a floating point number in mySQL?

Can I somehow store it as an INT?

I am thinking that VARCHAR is my best option, but if you guys know of anything better I would appreciate the input.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: what's wrong with mysql's FLOAT, REAL and DOUBLE_PRECISION types?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, just didn't know of them, I am primarily front end dev, not backend, but I am giving it a shot, hence all of the dumb questions, thank you for humoring me! :)

Comment: @user270311 floating point numbers has very little usage. What for you gonna use it?

Comment: I need to store prices incl VAT, and that requires me to somehow seperate the number, like this: 1234.50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a [Mysql Float](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) type.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what type of floating point number you are storing, all details regarding MySQL numeric types can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html

**DECIMAL:** For currency, you should use Decimal because its precise and you wont get weird decimal rounding in arithmetic.

**INT:** Yes you can store floats as ints to gain performance.  For example currency can be stored as $19.56 or 1956 as long as you always / 100 when displaying, accounting software does this often.  Furthermore you can store latitude / longitude as integers, 322274063, -1109654800 = 32.2274063, -110.9654800 as long as you divide by 10,000,000 when outside the database.

**FLOAT / DOUBLE:** And then of course there is long and double.  Use them when performance is not a priority or the number of decimal places varies.

**SO RULE:  If performance is an issue and you know the decimal places are always a fixed length, you can easily store an INT to store a FLOAT.**

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to store a floating-point as an int? MySQL has decimal and float types just like your programming language.

I'll assume you have a good reason. To store a float as an int, you can try a few things:

- Multiply the number by 10^n, where n is the number of significant digits you want to keep, and then truncate the rest of the fractional part. When you get it back out of the DB, convert to float/decimal and divide by n. This requires an int big enough to store the multiplied value; in 32-bit architecture, a "native" int can store values up to 2 billion.
- Split the number into its integer part and its fractional part. This requires two fields, but each field can have a value up to the maximum integer value, allowing you to easily have precision in the hundred-millionths.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to encode a floating point number in a flat format I'd recommend having a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008